# why is past perfect being used in the second sentence?

Tags: grammar

I have a problem with that sentence - "After landing in Entebbe, Uganda, the terrorists released all the passengers – except for around 100 Jews. The Germans had helped identify them using their passports and surnames".

Why the second sentence is in past perfect? What would be the difference if the second sentence would be "The Germans helped identify them using their passports and surnames"? Would that make any difference?

Here is the link to the whole article: https://www.spiegel.de/international/world/a-potential-rift-in-the-climate-movement-what-s-next-for-greta-thunberg-a-2491673f-2d42-4e2c-bbd7-bab53432b687

Comment: "with *this* sentence"; you would use "that" only if the sentence had already been mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the identification took place before the release. That's how the terrorists knew who the Jews were; they had already been identified before that point.

When talking about an event in the past, we use the pluperfect to indicate something else that was *already* in the past at the time of the event. The past of the past.